# Xlsxwriter - Writing a string to a cell given parameters

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I am looking to write a string to a cell using Xlsxwriter, however, it seems that I can only write to a specific cell in the following formats:

```
worksheet.write(0, 0, 'I like pie')
worksheet.write('A1', 'I like pie')
```

I am first writing a dataframe to the excel worksheet and then adding a footer at the bottom ('I like pie'). I would like the footer to be written in the cell below the the last line of the dataframe without manually telling python what exact cell to write to.

Any ideas? Maybe an if statement?

Comment: IF formula you mean?

Comment: Yes- meaning set parameters based on where the dataframe writes in excel

Comment: python openpyxl module (or xslw) does not support formulas. You can write them but they're not evaluated. Maybe post your code and we can see if an acceptable solution can be found.

Comment: I am only using xlsxwriter in this case, not openpyxl or xslw

Answer (score 3):

Use `df.shape` to get the number of rows for your dataframe, then use this number to specify the row for your footer:

```
nrows = df.shape[0]

worksheet.write(nrows, 0, 'I like pie')
# or: worksheet.write('A{}'.format(nrows+1), 'I like pie')
```

Comment: The [alternative notation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_cell_notation.html) `worksheet.write(nrows, 0, 'I like pie')` is probably better in this case.

Comment: So I tried added nrows = df.shape[0] and worksheet.write ( 'A{}'.format(nrows+1), 'I like pie') but it doesnt seem to be writing at the end of my dataframe. My dataframe is 16 rows by 12 cols and it is writing 11 rows down. Any ideas why?

Comment: @spacedinosaur10, what do you mean by saying that it's not writing to the end of your dataframe? Do you see 'I like pie' anywhere in your file? On what line? What numbers do you get, when you check the shape of your dataframe with df.shape?

Comment: @jmcnamara, thanks for your comment! I agree, this notation looks much better. I have added it to the answer.

Comment: @wombatonfire, So i start the dataframe at row 5 of the excel worksheet. And 'I like pie' prints on A15. The data frame is 16 rows long.

Comment: df.shape[0] will return the number of rows in your dataframe. If you see 'I like pie' in 'A15', than df.shape[0] should return 14. You can use that number directly if you write to excel file from the first line. If you skip any lines, than you should add the number of lines skiped (offset from the start) to the length of your dataframe. In your case, if you start from line 5, than add 4 to the length of the DF.